# Cordova Camera not working when application is build for android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, build

I am using the camera plugin for my Ionic application.
The camera is working fully when I try the browser application on the device, yet when I build and run the APK on my device the getPicture method is not fired.

```
$scope.takePictureBack = function () {
            $ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
                var cameraOptions = {
                    quality: 100,
                    targetHeight: 1080,
                    targetWidth: 1920,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
                };
                var success = function (data) {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        /*
                         remember to set the image ng-src in $apply,
                         i tried to set it from outside and it doesn't work.
                         */
                        $scope.cameraPicBack = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data;
                    });
                };
                var failure = function (message) {
                };
                //call the cordova camera plugin to open the device's camera
                navigator.camera.getPicture(success, failure, cameraOptions);
            })
        };
```

I have tried testing with logs, and it seems that neither the failure callback or the success callback of the methods are reached.

Does anyone know of any complications with the camera plugin. 
For the record my cordova and ionic is updated, and I am testing on a Galaxy s6 edge plus, with Android 6.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this code i had tested it on android device. it working as per your need.Simply you have to increase the camera option . Here are the options.

```
            quality: 75,
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            allowEdit: true,
            encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
            targetWidth: 300,
            targetHeight: 300,
            popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
            saveToPhotoAlbum: false
```

Futher if you have any query please feel free to contact me.